# Broken BIOS detected, complain to your hardware vendor. WTF?

Tags: linux, fedora, hp, bios, bug

This is what I found in dmesg on my new Fedora 16 instalation on new HP ProLiant DL320 G6

> > [    0.130963] Performance Events: PEBS fmt1+, Westmere events, Broken BIOS detected, complain to your hardware vendor.
> >     [    0.130971] [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)
> >     [    1.029118] BIOS reported wrong ACPI id for the processor

How bad it is and how to repair this ? Can I use this machine on production??

Comment: You can safely ignore this message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see: [Oracle Linux 6 kernel panic boot - anything I can do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/476874/oracle-linux-6-kernel-panic-boot-anything-i-can-do/476882#476882)

This is a harmless message. HP and [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/55862) insist that you can [safely ignore the error](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=5227546&spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c03265132-2%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

But in general, the most current firmware is [available here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3929673&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D3929672%257CprodNameId%253D3929673%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-9355a6870b5c4e21a45946c4e3%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). You may also want to download the [HP Firmware DVD](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3929673&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D3929672%257CprodNameId%253D3929673%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-7a8fd7561fb340388b2109cbed%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) to update all of the components in the system.

Answer (score 3):

That kind of messages can be seen sometimes.

Have you updated your Proliant firmware to latest version? Sometimes that fixes things.

Comment: It's a new server got it last week, so didn't make any updates. Is this error could be a reason of disaster, server crush reset etc...??

Comment: Give your server a nice little torture. Leave it running with `stress` or similar utils for a week or so, see if it still works or crashes. Usually those are harmless messages, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please see HP Customer advisory.
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03265132

According to HP and RedHat engineers I have talked to this is only a cosmetic error. There are ways of disabling some options in the HP Proliant ROM to hand over the control to OS and avoid seeing this message. The above article has that solution for up to Gen8 servers. For the Gen9 servers there are new procedures for UEFI ROM that HP will publish soon.

Otherwise this message can be completely ignored and there are no impact on the OS or the performance of the server.

Comment: This has been answered already. Three years ago.