# Oracle Linux 6 kernel panic boot - anything I can do?

Tags: linux, oracle, hp-proliant, rhel6, kernel-panic

I'm running Oracle Linux 6 on a HP Proliant server. It's been running fine for the last week, but seemed slow earlier so the Oracle service was stopped. Rather than restart the service, I was asked to reboot the server, but on start we got a kernel panic

First I get the following, which HP said isn't important, but I'm inclined not to believe them

> [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)
>   ERST: Can not request iomem region <0xffff88030c1dfe20-0xffff1006183bfc40> for ERST

Then the Kernel panic

> Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
>   Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.39-300.26.1.el6euk.x86-64 #1
>   Call Trace:
>    [<ffffffff81509077>] panic+0x91/0x1a8
>    [<ffffffff81061562>] ? enqueue_entity+0x52/0x210
>    [<ffffffff8107196b>] forget_original_parent+0x32b/0x330
>    [<ffffffff8105adbd>] ? sched_move_task+0x9d/0x150
>    [<ffffffff8107198b>] exit_notify+0x1b/0x190
>    [<ffffffff81072a8e>] do_exit+0x1fe/0x430
>    [<ffffffff81072d15>] do_group_exit+0x55/0xd0
>    [<ffffffff81072da7>] sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
>    [<ffffffff81514402>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
>   panic occurred: switching back to text console

Could anyone give me a pointer as to what is or even could be causing this? I'm completely stumped at this point. (System administration isn't my day job - I can get a server running but kernel panics are outside my comfort zone)

**Edit:**
Tested with the following kernels

> 2.6.39-300.26.1.el6euk.x86_64
>   2.6.39-200.24.1.el6euk.x86_64
>   2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64
>   2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64

Comment: What *specific* server model is it?

Comment: @ewwhite it's a HP ProLiant DL380 G7

Answer (score 1):

The first message you see during init: `[Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)` is not an issue. That's standard on EL6 and ProLiant systems. However, the [fix to remove the message is available here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03265132&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=5227546&prodTypeId=15351).

As for the crazy Oracle Linux kernel version, 2.6.39-300.26.1.el6euk.x86-64, can you try booting with the previous kernel in GRUB?

Comment: What's crazy about the kernel version? I'm not questioning you, I just don't know the difference. I believe there are 3 more options, I'll check what they are and get back to you.

Comment: Oh, it's because Oracle's Linux departs from the RHEL and CentOS standard with much newer kernels. Check the system boot with a different kernel.

Comment: @ewwwhite That would make sense: I'm running diagnostics at the moment, but if they don't come up with anything I'll try one of the other 3 kernels in GRUB. I'm not sure what they are right now, but I'll post the options before trying it out.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your server hardware. This is a kernel/OS interaction. Don't waste the time.

Comment: @ewwwhite The same error occurs with all 4 kernel options available (I've posted these in the main question as I can't put line breaks in the comment)

Comment: I fear an issue with an initial ramdisk. The server can't find its root filesystem, it seems... What type of storage is this system using? Local? SAN?

Comment: @ewwwhite A local 6-disk RAID-5 array

Comment: If I were you, I'd check the firmware on the server/controllers. Use the [**Firmware Update DVD**](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) or [**Service Pack for ProLiant DVD**](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/spp/index.html). Outside of that, it's possible that some autoupdating of packages could have rendered the system unbootable.

Comment: Willdo, cheers. We've ended up nuking the disk and re-installing - not ideal, but it's got us a working system again. I'll try to keep a closer eye on what gets updated in case anything similar happens. We've gone for CentOS this time, so I know exactly what's being installed - OracleLinux starts off with too many packages for my liking. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a hardware proble, memory, cpu or so. Try first to boot from a rescue disk (cd or usb disk) with memtest, and test it for some hours.

If you are a lucky man, you only have to replace ram, if you aren't ... may be you have to change the motherboad, cpu, ...

Comment: Memtest seems fine, but I'll run a longer test soon. Currently doing some diagnostics on the disks. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to come back to this - there was no hardware issue we ever found. After a re-install, the system has been rock solid for 18 months